# Возрастающая последовательность чисел

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Подскажите алгоритм или формулу или маленький пример, как происходит возрастающая последовательность чисел? Например, записаны три целых попарно неравных между собой числа в переменных a,b,c нужно, чтоб они шли по возрастанию.

Comment: omg! это что, сортировка теперь так формулируется?
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна сортировка. Это задание начального уровня на ветвление. Массивы и конкретные языки тоже не причем - обычно такое пишется псевдокодом. можно даже блок-схемой. 3 числа - это 2^3 = 8 вариантов. получится 3 уровня вложенности условных операторов

Comment: Ну, человек кагбе написал слово «например». Что заставляет предположить, что ему не нужно упорядочить _конкретно_ три числа.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то вопрос не совсем понятен. Зависит и от того, на каком языке будет программа. Многие языки могут просто отсортировать массив по возрастанию или убыванию.
Но если просто алгоритм сортировки делать руками, то можно сделать вот так. Например, создаем пустой массив `$massiv()`, затем подряд вносим в него числа `$massiv[a]=a`, `$massiv[b]=b`, `$massiv[c]=c` и так далее. И считываем массив по порядку - вот вам и отсортированный массив

Comment: На Javа использовать массив нельзя. Вот пример программы: 
Числа в переменных: a, b и c: 3, 9, -1. Возрастающая последовательность: -1, 3, 9

Comment: может я чего то не понимаю конечно но язык высокого уровня без массива это бред. http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/java/java3/10-doc.htm

Comment: Просто задание вот такое.
>В три переменные a, b и c явно записаны программистом три целых попарно неравных между собой числа. Создать программу, которая переставит числа в переменных таким образом, чтобы при выводе
на экран последовательность a, b и c оказалась строго возрастающей/

Просто нужно как вычислить по возрастающей последовательности.

Comment: Ну, если у вас явно только три переменные, то два раза прогнать цикл вот такой можно: `if (a<b) then x=a,a=b,b=x; if (b<c) then x=b,b=c,c=x;` и так как переменных три, то хватит два раза эти строчки прогнать. На свой язык сами переложите их.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, Grimon